# Finding pairs within a set of numbers

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and trying to write a simple poker playing game. If I have five cards, `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and want to check if any of them match (are a pair), then I think I could write a line like:

```
if a==b or b==c or a==c or ...  # ad nauseam
```

But I think there is a tool whereby you can effectively ask

> if any of `(a,b,c,d,e)` match, then...

However I don't know how to write it.

Comment: How did you model your "card" (and "hand") entities ? And what exact result do you expect ?

Comment: You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get the pairs of items.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the OP is trying to find out if his "set" (whatever he actually means by "set") actually contains any pair, not to generate pairs from the "set"

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes, and you can use `combinations` to get all combinations of two different items from the "set"; as you commented, without knowing how the objects are represented, it's hard to say exactly how this would be implemented (perhaps something like `any(c1 == c2 for c1, c2 in combinations(cards, 2))`), hence the comment.

Comment: @jonrsharpe uhu ok I see your point ;)

Comment: Another possibility might be to represent the hand as a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I can see there's at least two ways to check if a hand contains a pair. However still not sure how I would identify which particular cards were pairs, or assign them to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to get all the pairs of cards within the hand. To use a simple example:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> cards = (1, 2, 3, 4, 1)
>>> list(combinations(cards, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 1), (3, 4), (3, 1), (4, 1)]
```

Then you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) to see if any of these pairs are a match to each other:

```
>>> any(card1 == card2 for card1, card2 in combinations(cards, 2))
True
```

You should be able to adapt this to your representation relatively easily; if you have `Card` objects, for instance, this will call `Card.__eq__(card1, card2)`.

Note that I've used a sequence (tuple, or a list would also work) of five *"cards"*, rather than five separate identifiers (`a`, `b`, etc.); this makes the code more readable and flexible (the size of the hand is now irrelevant, so you can easily add [seven-card stud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-card_stud) to your poker game).

Comment: Or you could count if a number appears twice.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi yes, but note that that would be `O(N**2)` in the worst case, whereas this is (slightly) more efficient at `O((N*(N+1))/2)`

Comment: Note that if all you want to know is whether a number appears more than once in a list of numbers then it's easy as `len(yourlist) > len(set(yourlist))`

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator expression to pass into the `any` built-in:

```
if any(cards.count(i) >= 2 for i in cards): # cards is the tuple of number
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the fact that `set` does not contain multiple same elements, for example:

```
a=[1,1,2,2,3,3]
b=set(a)
print (b) # {1, 2, 3}
print len(a) == len(b) # False
```